# How much fuel to carry for melting snow?

Tags: snow, stoves

I'm using a multi fuel stove (MSR Dragonfly) for a 10 day ski tour, how much fuel should I allow to provide sufficient water for cooking and drinking. Meals will be mostly dehydrated just-add-water types. I'm not expecting to need much (any) for washing!

Comment: Don't forget to consider altitude and ambient temperatures for stove efficiency calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've heard from numerable places that when climbing Denali, plan on a cup (About .25 L) of white gas per person per day. I would say that this should be a good rule of thumb for your trip as well. You might be able to get away with a bit less, but this is at least a good rule of thumb.

You probably won't need this much, but it's a good rule of thumb still. Denali has additional challeneges, with the altitude it has, and from what I've heard, most climbers come down with extra gas.

Comment: By cup do you mean about a quarter of a litre?

Comment: @HorusKol: Good call, got to remember those people who have a sane unit system in the world...

Answer (score 6):

[10 inches of snow will give you 1 inch of water](http://www.enotes.com/science/q-and-a/how-much-water-there-an-inch-snow-289349).  Lets say you need to fill your container half way full to get a cup of water, well that means you're going to have to fill it full 5 times to get that cup, melting it each time.  I usually budget about 4-5 times the fuel in the winter than I use in the summer.

You can speed things up by pouring a bit of water in the bottom to begin with, and it'll also avoid the bottom of your pan scorching.